# Generate ctags for Ruby and Javascript

Tags: ctags

Currently I'm using this command to generate ctags:

```
ctags -R --languages=ruby,javascript --exclude=.git --exclude=log . $(bundle list --paths)
```

This works for Ruby, but not for the JavaScript. How can I fix that, so that JavaScript code will be in ctags too?

Comment: How are the definitions in the javascript files organized internally? Are they using the `(function (undefined) { <body> })();` thing? I just tried doing `find . -name '*.js' | xargs ctags -f-` and many of the js files are skipped.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet the .js files have that anonymous functions syntax, that's just a standard JavaScript using the modular pattern, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `--tag-relative` and `--sort=yes` fixed the problem.

```
ctags --tag-relative -R --sort=yes --languages=ruby,javascript --exclude=.git --exclude=log . $(bundle list --paths)
```

Comment: You might also be interested in https://rubygems.org/gems/starscope which uses an actual parser instead of regexes; a little slower, but hopefully more reliable and a bit easier to use.